# How to format Label's Text with StringFormat when the label is set as the binding source of slider?

Tags: maui

When a slider is used as the binding source, the formatter works as expected.

```xml
<HorizontalStackLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding Value, Source={Reference slider}, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}"  />
    <Slider x:Name="slider" WidthRequest="200"/>
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

But when I use a label as the binding source, the formatter does not work as expected.

```xml
<HorizontalStackLayout >
    <Label x:Name="label"  Text="{Binding StringFormat='{0:F2}'}"  />
    <Slider Value="{Binding Text, Source={Reference label}}"  WidthRequest="200"/>
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

[image]

How to fix the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, using the `Slider` as the binding source is better choice. The `Text="{Binding StringFormat='{0:F2}'}"` will not work for the binding source. And I can't find any way can do that in xaml.

But you can try to format the label's text in code behind when the label is binding source. Such as:

In the xaml:

```
<Label x:Name="label" PropertyChanged="label_PropertyChanged"/>
<Slider Value="{Binding Text,Source={Reference label}}" WidthRequest="300"/>
```

And in the code behind:

```
private void label_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     if(e.PropertyName == "Text")
     {
         (sender as Label).Text = String.Format("{0:0.##}",Convert.ToDouble((sender as Label).Text));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is `x:Reference` and `Reference` interchangeable or identical?

Comment: The official document didn't mention the `Reference`. So I suggest you use `x:Reference`. But in my test, they are the same. @DG